# Java missing pixels in gui?

Tags: java, pixel

I had to reinstall Windows and installed a fresh copy of Netbeans with the latest JDK.
I am experiencing an issue of missing pixels in Java application GUI's, see attached pictures. I even tried running it in a virtual machine. I also tried compiling jars with JDK 1.7 and reinstalling the latest Java.

Obviously, this bug appears only in my computer as I asked a friend to run my jar and he did not notice any missing pixels. These missing pixels appear in every jar I run.

[image]

Screen in fresh Windows installation virtual machine:

[image]

Comment: Does it happen with other applications?

Comment: You say "Windows", but the screenshot doesn't look like windows to me. If you have any WindowManager hacks installed, try uninstalling those. I've yet to see one that *really* works.

Comment: This is screen from virtual machine running fresh windows: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m5vnlah9u6ln3a/Screenshot%202014-05-19%2019.52.39.png

Comment: Either I'm not looking at the right thing or it looks like pixels are only missing from letters, which suggests a font / locale issue.

Comment: Could be true, well they are also missing in border of JTextArea ,but it can be also connected with some font issue.

Comment: If you don't reply to users' comments with @username they will not be notified. As for your problem, what elements are missing pixels when you run other jars?

Comment: @user1803551 This is for example Ubiquiti Discovery tool .. again missing letters and part of table header. Hard to say what elements are exaclty missing pixels ,but in most cases its text element...https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4qylleb4inju3o/Screenshot%202014-05-20%2017.57.36.png

Comment: or this is java control panel about: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ma0pmh5wm4ee8cg/Screenshot%202014-05-20%2018.01.04.png

Comment: I don't know, seems mostly like a font issue. If your Java version matches your Windows version and you're not using external tools then aside from hardware issues this is my guess.